# Redirect after few second in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, redirect, time

Is there a way to redirect after few second only by using rails?

I want when A user click on a link see the page and after few second get redirected to his profile(user_path)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because HTML is part of a Rails application you could use the standard html redirect option by default:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

Change `0` to number of seconds you want to wait before redirection.

On the other hand you could use javascript (also part of rails applications):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function delayedRedirect(){
    window.location = "/default.aspx"
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayedRedirect()', 3000)">
<h2>You'll be redirected soon!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I want to redirect the user_path, How can I do it without using rails?

Comment: @roine, just replace `"/default.aspx"` with `"<%= user_path %>"`.

Comment: @Mischa it works for you to replace `"/default.aspx"` with `"<%= user_path %>"` because for me it doesnt works. I dont think javascript can recognize rails tags

Comment: Yes, it works for me and you *can* mix Rails code and javascript like this. I've used it many times. I guess you are doing something wrong. Please update your question with your exact code and post any error messages you are getting.

Comment: FYI, for those having the above issue with being unable to use ERB tags (the `<%=` and `%>` tags), then you'll need to make the file an ERB file by appending `.erb` to the end of the file name of the precompilation file. Those tags are specific for ERB, not Rails.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [sleep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep) method

```
    sleep(2.0)
    redirect_to root_path
```

Comment: The problem is that the page is not show. I want to display a page and on this page wait for 2 second but it doesnt works

Comment: This will eat up two valuable seconds to the web worker and all subsequent requests to the server. I'd highly advise against this.